# Unable to verify the first certificate (Comodo EssentialSSL Wildcard)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am new to setting up SSL-certificates and working with servers in general, so please bear with me as I try to explain the situation I have put myself in.

I recently acquired an Comodo EssentialSSL Wildcard license that is going to be used for securing my server. The server I am configuring is for use with Kolab. Kolab is working but does not have SSL configured, so I figured I might set that up. I followed the instructions provided on the corresponding Kolab howto-page (https://docs.kolab.org/howtos/secure-kolab-server.html), but got stuck on the section where you set up the cyrus-IMAP server.

When running:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.org:993
```

I get the following output (truncated):

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = EssentialSSL Wildcard, CN = *.example.org
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = EssentialSSL Wildcard, CN = *.example.org
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = EssentialSSL Wildcard, CN = *.example.org
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.example.org
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.example.org
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2019 bytes and written 421 bytes
---
...

    Start Time: 1502097786
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN SASL-IR] example.org Cyrus IMAP git2.5+0-Debian-2.5~dev2015021301-0~kolab2 server ready
```

If I specify the -CApath to the certificates it does however work and I get the verify return code: 0 (ok), but only if I run the command while logged into the server through ssh. While setting up my mail on thunderbird I can access my mailbox, but have to first add an security exception because the certificate has an "Unknown Identity". The certificate does however work flawlessly on port 443 for https without specifying the -CApath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The intermediate certificates are missing and thus the trust chain can not be created. It might be different setup for https or it might be the same problem but browsers often work around this. See http://www.thawte.nl/en/support/manuals/cyrus/cyrus+imap+server/install+certificate/ for setting up cyrus imap with certificate chain.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thank you for the quick reply and for providing that link. I changed the .ca-bundle file I had previously created with the intermediate certificates to .pem and checked that the order of the intermediate certificates were correct. In the manual that you provided "tls_ca_path" was mentioned and since this was missing in my imapd.conf I added this and once again tried adding my account to thunderbird and did not have to add an exception. In other words, problem solved! Vielen dank :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking that the order of my intermediate bundle file was correctly formatted and changed it from a .ca-bundle to a .pem and added the following line to my imapd.conf:

```
tls_ca_path: /etc/ssl/certs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the following error while `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443`:

> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

You need to make sure you include [CA's Bundle](https://comodosslstore.com/resources/comodo-ca-bundle-certificate-chain/) certificates.

> When Comodo CA issues an SSL certificate, it will send along a specific Comodo CA bundle of intermediate certificates to install alongside it. These certificates create what is called a certificate chain. The end user certificate was signed using one of the intermediates, which was signed using one of the roots. When a browser arrives at a website it will attempt to build the certificate chain and chain the SSL certificate it’s being presented with back to one of the roots in its trust store.

Make sure you've downloaded these files from the certificate provider.

The most convenient way (especially for [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains)) is to merge all of them into one, for example by appending CA Bundle into the main CRT:

```
$ cat STAR_example_com.ca-bundle > STAR_example_com.crt
```

If you don't have a single `.ca-bundle` file (CA Bundle), but multiple files, merge them all into one.

Then install `STAR_example_com.crt` as usual. Example for Nginx:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/STAR_example_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/STAR_example_com.key;
```